# Or conditional in PHP - I think I have it right, but maybe not

Tags: php

I'm using the following OR conditional in PHP. I think I have it right, but I'm not sure. There's a lot of articles out there with so many different methods, it has me a little confused.

```
if ($SpecialProductType == 'dronecourseground' || 'dronecoursesafety') {
```

That is my conditional, if the value of $SpecialProductType is dronecourseground OR dronecoursesafety, then do the thing.

Am I missing something here?

Thank you.

Comment: `if ($SpecialProductType == 'dronecourseground' || $SpecialProductType == 'dronecoursesafety') {`

Comment: or `if (in_array($SpecialProductType, ['dronecourseground','dronecoursesafety'])) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($SpecialProductType == 'dronecourseground' || $SpecialProductType == 'dronecoursesafety') {
```

is valid code. The above is also right syntax, but leads to a faulty result.

Comment: _...The above is not...._ The code is valid too, but in the current case it doesn't lead to the required comparison

Comment: _..This was already solved in comments_ But not in the answers :) @GetSet

Comment: Seems like hijacking

Comment: Ok I'm not arguing with you bye